# What do the idioms "hang up", "hang on", and "hang out" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

What do *hang up*, *hang on*, and *hang out* mean?

Comment: They all have several different meanings, most of which can be found in any dictionary. I doubt you'll find much commonality apart from the fact that they all start with the same four-letter word.

Answer (score 12):

Collins Cobuild English dictionary:

> **hang up**
>
> means the same as **hang**: *"I found his jacket, which was hanging up in
>   the hallway".*
>
> if you **hang up** or **hang up** the phone, you end a phone call. If
>   you **hang up on** someone you are
>   speaking to on the phone, you end the
>   phone call suddenly and unexpected.
>
> You can use **hang up** to indicate that someone stops doing a particular
>   sport or activity that they have
>   regularly done over a long period. For
>   example, when a footballer **hangs
>   up** his boots, he stops playing
>   football.
>
> **hang-up**
>
> If you have a **hang-up** about something, you have a feeling of fear,
>   anxiety, or embarrassment about it.
>
> **hang on**
>
> If you ask someone to **hang on**, you ask them to wait or stop what they
>   are doing or saying for a moment.
>   *"Can you hang on for a minute?"*
>
> If you **hang on**, you manage to survive, achieve success, or avoid
>   failure in spite of great difficulties
>   or opposition. *"Manchester United
>   hung on to take the cup."*
>
> If you **hang on to** or **hang onto** something that gives you an
>   advantage, you succeed in keeping it
>   for yourself, and prevent it from
>   being taken away or given to someone
>   else. *"The British driver was unable
>   to hang on to his lead. ... The
>   company has been struggling to hang
>   onto its sales force."*
>
> If you **hang on to** or **hang onto** something, you hold it very
>   tightly, for example to stop it
>   falling or to support yourself. *"She
>   was conscious of a second man hanging
>   on to the rail. ... a flight
>   stewardess who helped save the life of
>   a pilot by hanging onto his legs. ...
>   He hangs on thightly, his arms around
>   my neck."*
>
> If you **hang on to** or **hang onto** something, you keep it for a
>   longer time than you would normally
>   expect. *"You could, alternatively,
>   hang onto it in the hope that it will
>   be worth millions in 10 years time.
>   ... In the present climate, owners are
>   hanging on to old ships."*
>
> If one thing **hangs on** another, it depends on it in order to become
>   successful. *"Much hangs on the
>   success of the collaboration between
>   the Groups of Seven governments and
>   Brazil."*
>
> **hang out**
>
> If you **hang out** clothes that you have washed, you hang them on a
>   clothes line to dry.
>
> If you **hang out** in a particular place or area, you go and stay there
>   for no particular reason, or spend a
>   lot of time there. (mainly American)
>   *"I often used to hang out in supermarkets. ... We can just hang out
>   and have a good time."*

All of these, like most idioms, are for informal use.

Comment: You can also encounter a **hang-up** in something (like a project), which means the project encountered a problem that is stopping progress (in an undesired way). Usually a **hang-up** indicates a problem that doesn't stop it for long (or is presumed to be quick to fix) (i.e. usually "a hang-up" is used interchangeably with "a minor hang-up" - by habit of usage, it is commonly said in a dismissive or minimizing way, but not always).